# Drawing a figure with two rectangular boxes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I need help in drawing the above figure in TikZ.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please have a look into "[How do I ask a good question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)". And please always [show what you've already reached](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and use this to describe your problem. Generally we do not like "*please, do it for me*" questions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what you have tried!  The short answer is that this can be done *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please do this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for tables, color, ... should give you something to start from. A tikz matrix of nodes is another possibility.

Comment: Post your code which produced the closest to that figure.

Comment: Have a look at page 1039: [PGF Man­ual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and that should help.